# On optimizing class creation

Tags: python, optimization, python-2.7

Let's say that I have to create a class that has a LOT of variables. Could I use a for loop to set each to it's self?
that is:

```
class New(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6):
        for x in [var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6]:
            self.x = x
```

Obviously the above code doesn't work, but is it possible to do this? A better way to do this?
rather than typing

```
self.var1 = var1
self.var2 = var2
```

etc.?

Comment: There are ways, yeah, but whenever I wanted something like that, I was either doing heavy metaprogramming (and thus there wasn't a fixed list of names and I had little choice), or a class was getting far too complex. Think about it. Perhaps your class is really just a container, perhaps a `collections.namedtuple`.

Comment: Hey delnan, I realize there are better/different ways to do it, I'm just trying to understand Python a little better. I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either store a list of attribute names ...

```
In [1]: class New(object):
   ...:    names = ['foo', 'bar']
   ...:    def __init__(self, *args):
   ...:        for k, v in zip(New.names, args):
   ...:            setattr(self, k, v)
   ...:             

In [2]: a = New(1, 2)

In [3]: a.foo
Out[3]: 1
```

or use keyword arguments:

```
In [1]: class New(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
   ...:         for k, v in kwargs.iteritems():
   ...:             setattr(self, k, v)
   ...: 

In [2]: a = New(foo=1, bar=2)

In [3]: a.foo
Out[3]: 1
```